# jquery - Why do these appended divs ignore their css?

Tags: jquery, css, html, append

I'm appending some div's with jquery.
And gave them size and color with css.
However they don't seem to pick up on the css?
And how can put some of the divs inside others

Here is my code
http://jsfiddle.net/Eqxzz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS for `#handler` matches *only* `id="handler"`, not `id="handlerXX"`, you should use a class and a class selector instead, like this:

```
'<div id="handler' + (counter) + '" class="handler">' + '</div>'
```

(Note the trailing space on the `id` is also removed, to be valid)  Also with matching CSS:

```
.handler { /* styles */ }
```

The same applies to `#drag` -> `.drag`, etc.  [You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/TFrxH/1/).

Comment: thank you! i understand but it still ignores the red from the drag div :o

Comment: @Opoe - it doesn't...the inner div is the same height/width, so it's just that the yellow `.handle` completely covers the area, look what happens when you give `.drag` a larger size: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/TFrxH/2/

Answer (score 1):

You have no CSS applying to #drag1, or #drag2, etc. I think you have classes and IDs mixed up here. Try using a class on your elements and apply the style through that class.

Answer (score 1):

you need to assign your CSS at a class level. see [my fork](http://jsfiddle.net/Eqxzz/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about css for #drag?

I see no #drag element in your HTML or being produced with JS.

You do create elements whose ID starts with drag and ends with a number, but #drag1, #drag2, #drag3.. they are all different than #drag.

Same goes for #handler.